# How to make wheat stalk stiffer in Cloth Physics?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I am making a wheat field that uses cloth physics to help each stalk move realistically with the wind. However before I convert the particle system, I need to look for the best numbers to plug into the properties of the cloth physics to ensure that the grass stays upright and springy. I have tried setting the tension and compression to 10,000, but it still bends sharply around the upper segments of the wheat stalk.

The hairs for the wheat also still seem to flail around like the strands of a mop. Is it possible to add specific nodes to the tension/compression properties to make these two areas stronger? If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know.

The images below are of the numbers I plugged into the Cloth Physics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect that using cloth sim for your purpose is not the best solution. Did you find any tutorial or online guide that suggests to use cloth to make the grass?

Comment: As @Sanbaldo cloth is probably not the best option, but i think you only need to put the gravity all the way down to 0 to keep it straight and from there, experiment with force field

Comment: yep @Emir, 0 gravity + vertex group with different weights to areas to give more stiffness to some part of the grass used as cloth pin + force field (maybe animated with a noise strength) can work. Still a lot a work I fear.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! I will be sure to try 0 gravity and force fields on the wheat. Where is the gravity setting?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found out about the Surface Deform Modifier, so I decided to try that on the wheat. I surrounded the wheat with a low-poly mesh, and gave the low-poly mesh the cloth modifier instead. To keep this mesh from falling over, I added pinning to a few vertices I extruded above the mesh. It works great now, not only because there is far less bending, but also because now I don't have to worry about the little hairs swinging all over the place.

Below is a screenshot of the wheat.

[image]